# Why does the app-auth service logout function in the angular template null the cookie instead of delete it?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

```
logout(reload?: boolean): void {
    abp.auth.clearToken();
    abp.utils.setCookieValue(
        AppConsts.authorization.encryptedAuthTokenName,
        undefined,
        undefined,
        abp.appPath
    );
    if (reload !== false) {
        location.href = AppConsts.appBaseUrl;
    }
}
```

Why is it using this code instead of the `deleteCookie` function?

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/059db7626b3642114b7a2ba7d15b6a14304640dd/src/Abp.Web.Resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js#L796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No particular reason. It has been changed to `deleteCookie` in [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template@`6cd84d7`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/commit/6cd84d79b1e0a295d322ba63db17cc2705dab531).

---

`deleteCookie(AppConsts.authorization.encryptedAuthTokenName, abp.appPath)` sets something like `enc_auth_token=; expires=Fri, 23 Apr 2021 00:00:00 GMT; path=/`, where `Fri, 23 Apr 2021 00:00:00 GMT` is 86400000 milliseconds (one day) ago.

- This causes the cookie to be deleted immediately.
- `getCookieValue` would return `null`.

`setCookieValue(AppConsts.authorization.encryptedAuthTokenName, undefined, undefined, abp.appPath)` sets something like `enc_auth_token=; path=/`, which is a session cookie.

- This causes the cookie to be deleted when the session ends.
- Before the session ends, `getCookieValue` would return `''` (as of ABP v6.3).

Comment: null vs '' is very different.
Null implies it isn't set.
'' implies it is.
Thanks for the answer, I opened an issue and it looks like it will be changed to Delete